# How to intercept the spring @Cacheable

Tags: spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

Say I have a springboot-based web app with such requirement: a service method annotated with @Cacheable.
when the cache is hit , I need to add some custom http header to the controller's response, how can I do that?

Comment: That seems difficult to do with `@Cacheable`

Comment: yes , I've try adding a custom CacheInterceptor , but it cannot be registered to spring cache